# VBA script optimisation to solve a puzzle with an underdetermined system

Tags: excel, vba

I received a puzzle when I just entered college and with my then lacking mathematical knowledge I wasn't able to solve it. Over the years I returned to the puzzle and was able to determine at least one solution and with my current still lacking mathematical knowledge I'm able to determine that the puzzle contains an underdetermined system of 10 formulas and 12 unknowns. At least one solution exists. My latest attempt in solving it was done with rudimentary programming skills in vba by bruteforcing all solutions. My scripts was able to find the solution I already had but was way to slow to determine any other solutions(my patience ran out before the script was done running).

The puzzle:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnXvZ.jpg).

I tried solving the multiple equations by looping through the variables and continuing with a next loop if a solution for the equation is found. While this works fine in thought, in practice it required a loop for each variable, in this case 12 which makes for a very slow process. I've tried making it quicker by moving some if statements earlier in the loops but this didn't really made a difference. I know that adding multiple loops inside each other doesn't make for good code but I can't think of something better.

With my lacking programming and mathematical skills I can't think of a quicker solution to solve the puzzle than looping through each variable. I was hoping for some help with this.

My code:

```
For a = 1 To 100
    For b = 1 To 100
        If 10 - a + 38 + b * 42 = 114 Then
            For c = 1 To 100
                For d = 1 To 100
                    For e = 1 To 100
                        If c - 2 + d + 6 * e = 37 Then
                            For f = 1 To 100
                                For g = 1 To 100
                                    If 50 - f * 3 - g / 5 = -4 Then
                                        For h = 1 To 100
                                            For j = 1 To 100
                                                For k = 1 To 100
                                                    If h + 15 - j * 3 - k = 2 Then
                                                        For l = 1 To 1000
                                                            For m = 1 To 100
                                                                If 20 * l + 12 / m + 8 = 171 Then
                                                                    If 10 + c * 50 + h + 20 = 186 Then
                                                                        If a * 2 - f + 15 - l = 111 Then
                                                                            If 38 - d * 3 - j + 12 = -28 Then
                                                                                If b + 6 + g - 3 * m = 27 Then
                                                                                    If 42 * e - 5 - k - 8 = 70 Then
                                                                                        r = r + 1
                                                                                        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 5).Value = a
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 6).Value = b
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 7).Value = c
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 8).Value = d
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 9).Value = e
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 10).Value = f
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 11).Value = g
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 12).Value = h
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 13).Value = j
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 14).Value = k
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 15).Value = l
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 16).Value = m
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 4).Value = Format(Timer - t, "hh:mm:ss")
                                                                                        End With
                                                                                    End If
                                                                                End If
                                                                            End If
                                                                        End If
                                                                    End If
                                                                End If
                                                            Next m
                                                        Next l
                                                    End If
                                                Next k
                                            Next j
                                        Next h
                                    End If
                                Next g
                            Next f
                        End If
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        End If
    Next b
Next a
```

In this example code I've only run it within the boundaries of 1 to 100 which gives me an solution after about 15 minutes. A range in which all solutions would be produces would probably take too long. So I'm kindoff stuck without help.

Comment: Thinking about an optimized solution would take time but in your current implementation, you are not breaking of the loops when you solve something.

Comment: From what I can see, that seems to be the point @CetinBasoz since they're increasing the row number and probably trying to see if there are multiple solutions.

Comment: @Notus_Panda, Yes but it wouldn't do any good since other possibilities are not saved, say in an array. Unfortunately my VBA is extremely rusty to even try doing it VBA. Using too many for loops just doesn't sound right to me in solving this.

Comment: Never said it's the *right* way to solving this, just saying that with that all the correct answers (if any/more than one) are being written to the sheet so exiting a loop at the first correct one seems counterproductive in his code as it is now. The right way is simplifying the math to which you can adjust code to but that's for someone with more time :p

Comment: Is there any wording to go with the puzzle? Usually with these sort of puzzles evaluation is from left to right rather than algebraically which could make a big difference.

Comment: ...but then 114 isn't a multiple of 42 so there could be no integer solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it considered cheating to simplify some of the equations? You can define 7 of the variables in terms of other variables, so instead of looping for 12 variables, you only have to loop for 5.

I tried your original way and gave up after 3 minutes of running. I tried with the simplified variables and it only took 4 seconds. I also tried 1 to 200 and -100 to 100, and still only 1 solution. Those runs took less than a minute so you might find more solutions if you're willing to wait.

I also changed your 1 to 100 to variables to make it easier to expand the range and test for negative solutions.

```
Sub solve_problem()

intMIN = 1
intMAX = 150

Start = Now

For a = intMIN To intMAX
'    For B = intMIN To intMAX
    b = (a + 66) / 42
        If 10 - a + 38 + b * 42 = 114 Then
            For c = intMIN To intMAX
                For d = intMIN To intMAX
                    For e = intMIN To intMAX
                        If c - 2 + d + 6 * e = 37 Then
                            For f = intMIN To intMAX
'                                For g = intMIN To intMAX
                                g = 270 - 15 * f
                                    If 50 - f * 3 - g / 5 = -4 Then
'                                        For h = intMIN To intMAX
                                        h = 156 - (50 * c)
'                                            For j = intMIN To intMAX
                                            j = 78 - 3 * d
'                                                For k = intMIN To intMAX
                                                k = 42 * e - 83
                                                    If h + 15 - j * 3 - k = 2 Then
'                                                        For L = intMIN To intMAX
                                                        l = 84 * b - f - 228
'                                                            For m = intMIN To intMAX
                                                            m = 12 / (163 - 20 * l)
                                                                If 20 * l + 12 / m + 8 = 171 Then
                                                                    If 10 + c * 50 + h + 20 = 186 Then
                                                                        If a * 2 - f + 15 - l = 111 Then
                                                                            If 38 - d * 3 - j + 12 = -28 Then
                                                                                If b + 6 + g - 3 * m = 27 Then
                                                                                    If 42 * e - 5 - k - 8 = 70 Then
                                                                                        r = r + 1
                                                                                        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 5).Value = a
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 6).Value = b
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 7).Value = c
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 8).Value = d
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 9).Value = e
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 10).Value = f
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 11).Value = g
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 12).Value = h
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 13).Value = j
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 14).Value = k
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 15).Value = l
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 16).Value = m
                                                                                            .Cells(r, 4).Value = Format(Now - Start, "hh:mm:ss")
                                                                                        End With
                                                                                    End If
                                                                                End If
                                                                            End If
                                                                        End If
                                                                    End If
                                                                End If
'                                                            Next m
'                                                        Next L
                                                    End If
'                                                Next k
'                                            Next j
'                                        Next h
                                    End If
'                                Next g
                            Next f
                        End If
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        End If
'    Next B
Next a

r = r + 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4).Value = Format(Now - Start, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

Here is the work for isolating the variables

[image]

Comment: I also simplified to `E=(39-C-D)/6` and came up with a second, non-integer, non-positive solution: 60,3,19,67,-7.833333333,16,30,-794,-123,-412,8,4

Answer (score 1):

That was fun :-)
I think, there is only one solution (From A to M):
60,3,3,24,2,16,30,6,6,1,8,4

You need a Sheet called output.
**DoAll** is the sub to start
The trick is first to find the horizontal.
For 100 Const lo (loop constant) it needs ~ 1 sec.
if you go higher it will get much slower and i doubt there is another solution.
But that's left to you :-)

```
Option Explicit
Const lo As Long = 100
Const di As Long = 1000000
Dim Field1() As Long
Dim Field2() As Long
Dim Field3() As Long
Dim Field4() As Long
Dim Field5() As Long
Dim Field6() As Long
Dim Field7() As Long
Dim Field8() As Long
Dim Field9() As Long
Dim Field10() As Long
Dim Field11() As Long
Dim Field12() As Long

Sub DoAll()
    FirstLine
    SecondLine
    ThirdLine
    FourthLine
    FifthLine
    CheckVert
End Sub

Sub FirstLine()
    ReDim Field1(di)
    ReDim Field2(di)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, counter As Long
    counter = -1
    For a = 1 To lo
        For b = 1 To lo
            If 10 - a + 38 + b * 42 = 114 Then
                counter = counter + 1
                Field1(counter) = a
                Field2(counter) = b
            End If
        Next b
    Next a
    ReDim Preserve Field1(counter)
    ReDim Preserve Field2(counter)
    Debug.Print " First Line "; counter
End Sub

Sub SecondLine()
    ReDim Field3(di)
    ReDim Field4(di)
    ReDim Field5(di)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, counter As Long
    counter = -1
    For a = 1 To lo
        For b = 1 To lo
            For c = 1 To lo
                If a - 2 + b + 6 * c = 37 Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                    Field3(counter) = a
                    Field4(counter) = b
                    Field5(counter) = c
                End If
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
    ReDim Preserve Field3(counter)
    ReDim Preserve Field4(counter)
    ReDim Preserve Field5(counter)
    Debug.Print " Second Line "; counter
End Sub

Sub ThirdLine()
    ReDim Field6(di)
    ReDim Field7(di)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, counter As Long
    counter = -1
    For a = 1 To lo
        For b = 1 To lo
            If 50 - a * 3 - b / 5 = -4 Then
                counter = counter + 1
                Field6(counter) = a
                Field7(counter) = b
            End If
        Next b
    Next a
    ReDim Preserve Field6(counter)
    ReDim Preserve Field7(counter)
    Debug.Print " Third Line "; counter
End Sub

Sub FourthLine()
    ReDim Field8(di)
    ReDim Field9(di)
    ReDim Field10(di)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, counter As Long
    counter = -1
    For a = 1 To lo
        For b = 1 To lo
            For c = 1 To lo
                If a + 15 - b * 3 - c = 2 Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                    Field8(counter) = a
                    Field9(counter) = b
                    Field10(counter) = c
                End If
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
    ReDim Preserve Field8(counter)
    ReDim Preserve Field9(counter)
    ReDim Preserve Field10(counter)
    Debug.Print " FourthLine  "; counter
End Sub

Sub FifthLine()
    ReDim Field11(di)
    ReDim Field12(di)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, counter As Long
    counter = -1
    For a = 1 To lo
        For b = 1 To lo
            If 20 * a + 12 / b + 8 = 171 Then
                counter = counter + 1
                Field11(counter) = a
                Field12(counter) = b
            End If
        Next b
    Next a
    ReDim Preserve Field11(counter)
    ReDim Preserve Field12(counter)
    Debug.Print " FifthLine Line "; counter
End Sub

Sub CheckVert()
    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim z As Long
    Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
    w.UsedRange.ClearContents
    Dim a, b, c, d, e
    For a = 0 To UBound(Field1)
        For b = 0 To UBound(Field3)
            For c = 0 To UBound(Field6)
                For d = 0 To UBound(Field8)
                    For e = 0 To UBound(Field11)
                        Call DoVertOutput(Field1(a), Field2(a), Field3(b), Field4(b), Field5(b), Field6(c), Field7(c), Field8(d), Field9(d), Field10(d), Field11(e), Field12(e), w, z)
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub

Sub DoVertOutput(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, w As Worksheet, ByRef z)
    If 10 + c * 50 + h + 20 = 186 Then
        If a * 2 - f + 15 - l = 111 Then
            If 38 - d * 3 - j + 12 = -28 Then
                If b + 6 + g - 3 * m = 27 Then
                    If 42 * e - 5 - k - 8 = 70 Then
                        z = z + 1
                        w.Cells(1, z) = a
                        w.Cells(2, z) = b
                        w.Cells(3, z) = c
                        w.Cells(4, z) = d
                        w.Cells(5, z) = e
                        w.Cells(6, z) = f
                        w.Cells(7, z) = g
                        w.Cells(8, z) = h
                        w.Cells(9, z) = j
                        w.Cells(10, z) = k
                        w.Cells(11, z) = l
                        w.Cells(12, z) = m
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```